# rewrite url only and stay on the same page

Tags: url-rewriting

I have read a lot on stack about rewriterule and how it applies and I've tried reading up on some good articles online but I still cannot wrap my head around a few things.

I have blogs setup where all folders are in 
https://domain.ca/posts/post-tree/*

So I've setup htaccess like this

```
RewriteRule ^posts/post-tree/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [R=301]
```

As I'm sure you can guess this basically brings me root index.php where I catch this request with a $_GET to know the name of the blog folder it was requesting.

This is fine I can hit index.php and with $_GET I know the blog page they requested.

What I do not get, and I've tried a lot of things, is once I have this request in index.php how do I re-write the URL to show something like https://domain.ca/blogpage/ instead of looking like https://domain.ca/index.php? where https://domain.ca/blogpage/ does not really exist of course, but it is because I want to hide the http://domain.ca/posts/post-tree/ path.

Its a little like when wordpress processes a blog page with the id and after rewrites the url to whatever slug is set for that blog page.  at least my understanding of it as they don't have individual folders for blogs, but I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working with the following in the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#   the above checks if file or folder exists, if not the below is processed
#   this will route to base index file and fetch $1 folder via $_GET

RewriteRule . /posts/post-tree/index.php?$1
```